# how can i download database throgh api and get.request?

Tags: python

I try to download the database through Api.
I extract the name of data through csv file and I try to iterate the url through the list. but in last step: get.request I get the error and non of the input can not be recognized,
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import json
import urllib
import os
from pandas import *

data = read_csv("A3D_Human_Database.csv")

job_iden = data['job_id'].tolist()

for d in job_iden:
    p = d[0:14]
    print(f"downloading {p}")
    req = requests.get('http://biocomp.chem.uw.edu.pl/A3D2/RESTful/hproteome_job/{p}/')
    print(req.status_code)
```

Comment: your url string includes a `{p}` formatting instruction but python doesn't know it is an f-string because there's no `f` before the opening quote

Comment: also you should include the error message you're getting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.